# Is there a way to detect remote desktop session events in NPLogonNotify

Tags: windows, authentication, remote-desktop, winlogon, terminal-services

Remote desktop connections to existing sessions triggers the NPLogonNotify in the network provider. But is there a way i can figure out if its a login event or a connect event to an existing session?

Answer (score 1):

[LsaGetLogonSessionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the terminal services session ID from the logon session ID.  So you could try calling [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WTSConnectState.  With luck, the result will differentiate the two cases you're concerned with.

If not, and if you don't need to know the answer before returning from NPLogonSession, you could watch the what happens to the terminal services session associated with the call to NPLogonSession, perhaps using [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I believe that if the user is connected to an existing session, the terminal services session from NPLogonNotify will return to the idle or listen state.  Also, the logon session in the call to NPLogonNotify will be closed.  You can enumerate logon sessions by calling [LsaEnumerateLogonSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If the user receives a new session, I believe that the same terminal services session in the call from NPLogonNotify will be used, so it will move into the active state.  There will usually also be one or more processes started which are associated with the logon session ID from the call to NPLogonNotify.  You can determine the logon session associated with a process by using [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the TokenStatistics query class, as described under ["logon identifier"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721592(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_logon_identifier_gly) in the MSDN glossary.

One additional complication to be aware of: if the user is an administrator, and UAC is enabled, there will be two calls to NPLogonNotify, one associated with the restricted user token and the other with the elevated user token.  This is true for both local and remote logons.